# Can not copy a file from ubuntu 18.04 pc to a usb connected to a router

Tags: 18.04

Upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and lost the ability to copy a file from my PC to the USB connected to my router if the file is more that 512Kb.
I can copy from the USB on the router to my PC with no problems. The message I get says the network is being reset.

Additional information per request:

```
adam@adam-desktop:~$ journalctl --since="- 10 minutes"
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-10-02 13:27:30 CDT, end at Mon 2019-05-06 12:11:20 CDT
May 06 12:01:33 adam-desktop systemd-resolved[546]: Grace period over, resuming 
May 06 12:01:33 adam-desktop systemd-resolved[546]: Using degraded feature set (
May 06 12:10:20 adam-desktop gnome-shell[1231]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gno
May 06 12:10:20 adam-desktop gnome-shell[1231]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback 
                                                getCurrentRect@resource:///org/g
                                                wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gj
                                                _onFocusPositionChanged@resource
                                                wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gj
                                                _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/
                                                _setCurrentWindow/this._currentW
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop dbus-daemon[1008]: [session uid=1000 pid=1008] Acti
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop systemd[823]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop dbus-daemon[1008]: [session uid=1000 pid=1008] Succ
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop systemd[823]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
lines 1-15/15 (END)...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-10-02 13:27:30 CDT, end at Mon 2019-05-06 12:11:20 CDT. --
May 06 12:01:33 adam-desktop systemd-resolved[546]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 192.168.1.1.
May 06 12:01:33 adam-desktop systemd-resolved[546]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.1.1.
May 06 12:10:20 adam-desktop gnome-shell[1231]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js 546]: reference to undefined property "_rect"
May 06 12:10:20 adam-desktop gnome-shell[1231]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: position-changed: TypeError: this._rect is undefined
                                                getCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:546:22
                                                wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                                _onFocusPositionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:611:20
                                                wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
                                                _emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27
                                                _setCurrentWindow/this._currentWindowPositionId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:528:21
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop dbus-daemon[1008]: [session uid=1000 pid=1008] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.serv
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop systemd[823]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop dbus-daemon[1008]: [session uid=1000 pid=1008] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
May 06 12:11:20 adam-desktop systemd[823]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
```

Comment: Show us the command you're using, and the complete error message. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1139250/edit ) your post to add the info, and format it with the `{}` tool.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by show us the command, All I am doing is right clicking on a file on my pc, selecting the copy command, changing to the smb://readyshare/ location on my usb connected to my router. select a folder, do a right click with the mouse, and select paste. It creates a file with 0 bites and the says dropped network connection with reset.

Comment: Are there any suggestions to my issue?

Comment: Get more information. Try your copy again, then, in a terminal window, `journalctl --since="- 10 minutes"`.

Comment: Are there any suggestions to my issue?

Comment: Since I have not receive any response to this issue, I have reverted back to Ubuntu 16.04 using the ChaletOS configuration which has resolved my issue. So much for using the latest version. Disappointed. May need to go back to Windows when the support for 16.04 runs out in a year or two.